# How to change css using jquery in a php loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I want to change the css of my textbox and to disabled the submit button in a php loop if it meets certain condiion .

I've successfully manage to loop the data through php but only the first textbox is changed

I'll put a few part of the php codes as php part is already done succesfully

Script

```
<style type="text/css">
.first
{
  color:#0C0
}
.second
{
   color:#F00
}

</style>

 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" > </script>
 <script> var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 function changeClass(str)
 {
      if ($j('#status').val()== "No")
      {
          $j('#status').addClass('first');
      }
  else
  {
         $j('#status').removeClass('first');                                
         $j('#status').addClass('second');                   
         $j('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
       }              
return true;
 }
  </script>
```

### HTML

```
 <table width="800" border="0" align="center" bordercolor="#000000" 
          onmousemove="changeClass(this);"> 
 <?php do { ?>
     <tr bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
       <th  align="center" bgcolor="#3366FF" class="style68" >Status</th>
       <th  align="center" bgcolor="#3366FF" class="style68" >Submit</th>
       <td  align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
          <form  > <input type="text"  id="status" name="status" 
           value="<?php echo$data['status']; ?>" >
       </td> 
       <td  align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
         <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" > Submit</button>
    </form>
   </td>
         </td>
                 </tr>   
                  <?php } while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($re)); ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: how many elements are there with id 'status'?, I mean is it repeating too?

Comment: the textbox with id="status" will be repeated.

Comment: Thats the problem you cant use same id for multiple elements.Thats the problem you cant use same id for multiple elements. If you want to change the style of all you have to use the same class for all elements.

Comment: Perhaps you should give it the same class and have an incrementing id.

Comment: @arjuncc how can I do that ? I don't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: @user1852728 checkout the answer. I have posted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').hover(function(){
    $( ".changeClass" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).val()=='No')
    {
    $(this).addClass( "second" );
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.submitClass').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).addClass( "first" );
    }
    });
    return true;
    })
});



  <input type="text" class="changeClass"  name="status"  value="<?php echo$data['status']; ?>" >
```

Comment: shorthand `$j('.changeClass').removeClass('first').addClass('second');`

Comment: Does this mean that the codes will add another class inside the class ?

Comment: @user1852728 sorry, i dont understand what do you meant to say

Comment: @user1852728: Not inside, you can have few class in the same element, like `class="first second third"`, on the other hand, you can only have one id, `#idname` is the jquery selector based on id and '.classname' is for select an element based on the class name

Comment: @arjuncc sorry for the late reply, it didn't work quite yet,
right now if the first value from my database ="No", then then, all of the textbox will have the same class as the first one Which is the font turning green. If the first value !="No", then all of the textbox will have the second class which is the font turning red and submit button  disabled.

Comment: @user1852728 exactly what you want to achieve? when should the inputs change the colour(on what event)?

Comment: @arjuncc what i want to do is:


onmouse move over the table, the colour of the results queried from the database into the textbox will change according to the value.


If the value == "No", the add the class "first" which turn the colour of the font into green.
Else
Add the class "second" which turn the colour of the font into red.

Comment: @arjuncc what i want to do is:

onmouse move over the table, the colour of the results queried from the database into the textbox will change according to the value.

If the value == "No", the add the class "first" which turn the colour of the font into green.Else
Add the class "second" which turn the colour of the font into red and disabling the submit button.
Whats happening right now is that, each textbox that loops after the first textbox will follow the class of the first textbox, if the first texbox value != No, all of the succeeding text in the texbox  will turn red.

Comment: @user1852728 now I get it. I have updated the answer.check it

Comment: @arjuncc the latest code didn't work at all, before this  every textbox that loops after the first textbox will follow the class of the first textbox eventhough it has different values but right now it does not work at all

Comment: @arjuncc I've manage to make it work after editing your codes, but the problem right now is that no watter what the values in the textbox. the submit button will always be disabled.

Comment: jfiddle your code. And also one question, how many submit buttons u have?

Comment: I have a fiddle for you, This is what i understood from your requirement. If its not what you want. Then clear me.
http://jsfiddle.net/QTp4X/1/

Comment: The submit button is for each line of value being outputted as in my picture here. its in a loop, so if there is 3 values from the database being output, there will be 3 submit button

Unfortunately, my codes required a database to be working but,I uploaded a picture for your reference 

[picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/37/65794561.png/)

As you can see, i want the submit button to be enabled if the textbox beside it has the first class..

Comment: @user1852728 updated according to your requirement, Now check It http://jsfiddle.net/QTp4X/2/

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thanks very much, it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Elements id in HTML must be unique. You should use the table id and go through the tables td children to do it. Or you can use the td class status and call them .status instead of #status in jquery.